# Create a distribution build with core plot?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, distribution

I need to make a distribution build for my application.

Im using Core Plot inside my project. I have my main project and inside I added the Core Plot project. My app is working fine and I'm ready to publish it. I want to archive and submit it to the app store. But here comes the problem. This is version 1.1 of my app (not sure if this even matters). When I archive it, I can not validate or submit it.
It says:

```
“MyApp” does not contain a single–bundle application or contains multiple products. Please select another archive, or adjust your scheme to create a single–bundle application.
```

How am I supposed to address this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your scheme, select the *Build* section, and check you only have one target ticked for *Archive*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems that this is not the case. I have only one target there. What else could be causing this? I can post some screen shots if needed, just tell me what :)

Comment: Check that the Core Plot project has *Skip Install* set to *Yes*.  Failing that, I suggest creating a new project and using the same method to add Core Plot to it, then uploading it somewhere where people can see it.

Comment: I found it in build settings of the Core Plot project. Is this the place? It was set to `No` and I set it to `Yes`. I tried to archive it again and still no luck. Am I missing something again?

Comment: Did you try this with a new project?

Comment: Yes I tried creating a new project and followed this tutorial: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application. This is the one I used in the other project as well. Is there anything wrong with it? I really need to fix it.

Comment: Ok I fixed it. You were right. I just needed to move all the files in copy headers in build phases to the "project". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found this:
http://astralbodies.net/blog/2011/03/27/xcode-4-problem-submitting-app-with-static-library/
then it worked like magic! (I tried doing only parts of it, didn't work, you have to do all :))